# Wireless keeps disconnecting in Ubuntu 12.04.03

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

Internet works fine with wired connection, but with wireless it keeps discontinuing. On Windows, it works fine in both cases. I have installed Ubuntu side by side to windows creating separate partition.

Following is result of lspci command:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5229 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

Could anybody please help me on this issue? I have gone through several threads, but did not find the exact solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/902557) on the driver that hasn't been fixed in Precise. There are some workarounds in the web, but the results aren't consistent (some works for somebody, others not).

- **[Replace the drivers](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1981968&p=12012093#post12012093)**
- **[Configure the driver](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1981968&p=12373496#post12373496)**

For now, click the "Yes, it affects me" button and wait for a fix.

[image]